# j2me wtk find memory leak

Tags: java-me, out-of-memory, java-wireless-toolkit

I built a game in j2me and I have memory leak because from time to time I get out of memory exception, now I want to spot where this leak is coming from and I heard you can do it with sun's wireless tool kit. Can someone explain me exactly what is this wireless tool kit, how I install it and how to use it in-order to find memory leaks ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: just tried to run it using sun's wtk emulator and I got alot of errors so I rather stick with my previous emulator Im currently using oracle sdk 3.4 emulator for j2me anyway to find memory leaks using it ?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#sun_java_wireless_toolkit-2.5.2_01b-oth-JPR

Answer (score 0):

After you download wtk,Go to \bin\utilsw.exe.Under Utilities you will see "Memory monitor".Here you can graphically view app memory/RAM usage.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know oracle sdk 3.4, but in wtk2 memory monitor was only partially useful for finding memory leaks, because it only shows how many (and which) objects are live, but not where they are referenced from. So it takes a review of corresponding piece of code.

Memory leaks are easier to find with a java profiler. You need to get one that suits you (I prefer YourKit, but it is commercial product with a trial period), modify emulator's command line in order to allow the profiler to connect (that should be covered by profiler's documentation, it is basically about adding `-agentlib` or `-Xrun...` option) to it, and do actual profiling (every profiler comes with a guide of how to do it).